# A view with two patial views (both contain a form) causes validation on both forms when one is submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a parent view with two partial views rendered on it.

Each of the partial views has its own form which I post to.

When I submit one of the forms both of them validate (server side).

How can I prevent this?

Both forms are set to post to the parent view.

**Code**

### A sign in page with a partial view for siging in and a partial view for registering. Both partial views contain forms.

### Index.cshtml

```
    @{Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "LogOn");}
    @{Html.RenderAction("Register", "Register");}
```

### SignInController.cs

```
public class SignInController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
}
```

### _LogOn.cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SignIn", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
```

### LogOnController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
    {

        return this.PartialView("_LogOn", model);
    }
```

### _Register.cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SignIn", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
```

### RegisterController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {

        return this.PartialView("_Register", model);
    }
```

Comment: Do they have different `ActionResult`s

Comment: Both the POST actions for the partial views return this.PartialView(partialview,model)